# js проверка id у section

Tags: javascript, html

Есть

```
<section id="portfolios-xxx">
```

как на js проверить id этого самого section и если он выглядит **portfolios-** то выполнять действие.

Answer (score 2):

Можно просто использовать селектор `[id^=portfolios-]`, что означает id должен начинаться с portfolios.

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('section[id^=portfolios-]')

for (el of elements) {
  el.style.color = 'red'
}
```

```html
<section id="portfolios-xxx">portfolios-xxx</section>
<section id="port-aaaa">port-aaaa</section>
<section id="1337portfolios321">1337portfolios321</section>
<section id="portfolios-aaaa">portfolios-aaaa</section>
```

Comment: Только учесть то, что если id = portfolioss-aaa он также будет считаться как  нужный ID.

Comment: Спасибо, поправил, забыл про `-`

Answer (score 0):

**Jquery:**

```js
$.each( $("section"), function( key, value ) {
  if($(value).attr("id").indexOf("portfolios-") != -1)
  {
    alert($(value).attr("id"))
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="portfolios-aaa"></section>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<section id="portfolios-bbb"></section>
<section id="sections-aaa"></section>
```

**JavaScript:**

```js
var objSections = document.getElementsByTagName('section');
var len = objSections.length;

for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  if(objSections[i].id.indexOf("portfolios-") != -1)
  {
    alert(objSections[i].id)
  }
}
```

```html
<section id="portfolios-aaa"></section>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<section id="portfolios-bbb"></section>
<section id="sections-aaa"></section>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let checkId = document.getElementsByTagName('section');
for (item of checkId){
    if(~item.id.indexOf("portfolios-"))
  {
    console.log(item.id);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="portfolios-xxx">
<section id="port-aaaa">
<section id="portfolios321">
<section id="portfolios-aaaa">
```

Comment: А как это сделать без Jquery ?

Comment: Обновил свой ответ

Comment: Обновил код в  ответе.